# Automatic root login inside docker container with systemd as PID 1

Tags: linux, docker, containers, systemd, init

I have been trying to make my docker container to make automatic root login with systed as PID 1.

Below is the modification in Dockerfile for systemd to automatic login as root user without any prompt and return shell access.

[image]

Docker run command:

```
docker run -it  -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock --tmpfs /tmp --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --name=tty4 tty4
```

returns this output.

[image]

It should be automatically able to login into this container as shown in the screenshot above.

So far i have tried :

[image]

[image]

Also we tried setting shell script as a ENTRYPOINT. Below are the contents of the shell script.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note :

- I don't want to use podman.
- Docker run should return the terminal prompt with systemd running as PID 1 in one go.
- I dont want to run container as a daemon then exec into , it should be run and exec in one go.

Comment: So, you're trying to set up a virtual machine?  A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process; it doesn't usually have ttys, interactive logins, multiple users, and so on, and I'd generally recommend against running systemd in a container if you have any choice at all.

Comment: Hi David , we are doing it in a docker container . The requirement is to use multiple services in a container itself not in a VM.

Comment: if you're trying to run systemd, multiple services, interactive logins, and that sort of thing, it really sounds like you're building a virtual machine, and running a standard Linux distribution in a VM will be much easier.

Comment: I just want to remove interactive login. I don't wanna use VM coz the requirement is strictly using docker.